# IMAP responses repeating

Tags: c#, imap

Can somebody explain IMAP server responses behavior?
When I send single command, response meets expectations:

```
C: A0001 FETCH 10 (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)])
S: * 10 FETCH (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)] {21}
   Subject: FW: test

   )
   A0001 OK FETCH completed.
```

But if I send several command one by one, responses behavior is unclear:

```
C: A0001 FETCH 10 (BODY[HEADER])
S: * 10 FETCH (BODY[HEADER] {1632}
   ...
   A0001 OK FETCH completed.
C: A0002 FETCH 10 (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)])
S: * 10 FETCH (BODY[HEADER] {1632}
   ...
   A0001 OK FETCH completed.
C: A0003 FETCH 10 BODY[TEXT]
S: * 10 FETCH (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)] {21}
   Subject: FW: test

   )
   A0002 OK FETCH completed.
```

Why are the responses repeated? And how to fix it? [Code](https://github.com/shmonoff/automatization/blob/master/IMAP/issue.cs)

Comment: Are you really receiving: `A0001 OK FETCH completed.` twice?  That indicates a buggy server.

Comment: @Max Yes, I noticed that responses always double. Is it server's bug?

Comment: It seems more likely that your client has some sort of buffering bug and is not sending what you think it is...

Comment: @Max I'm using request function based on [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Simple-IMAP-CLIENT-b249d2e6) example...

Comment: Please show /your/ code, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that writing to the ssl stream occurred in a read loop from the ssl stream.